# Planning of integrator and derivator circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I have to plan a circuit given by the series of an integrator and a derivator circuit. I haven't planned a circuit before, so I ask you if my reasoning is correct.

The only condition that I have to satisfy is that the angular frequency I will apply to my circuit must be in the range beteewn 1k rad/s and 10k rad/s.

The fist part of the circuit has to be an integrator and the second one a derivator.

Let's call \$R_1\$the resistence and \$C_1\$ the capacity of the integrator.

Let's call \$R_2\$the resistence and \$C_2\$ the capacity of the derivator.

I have to satisfy these two conditions: \$\omega_1<<\omega\$ and \$5\omega<<\omega_2  \$, where \$\omega_1=\frac{1}{R_1 C_1}\$ and \$\omega_2=\frac{1}{R_2 C_2}\$

I consider \$\omega_1=\frac{1}{10}\omega\$ so its value can be between 100 and 1000 rad/s.

If \$\omega_1=\frac{1}{R_1 C_1}\$=100 -> \$R_1=\frac{1}{\omega_1 C_1}\$ and, if \$C_1=47*10^-9\$ F, \$R_1=2.1*10^5 \Omega\$

If \$\omega_1=\frac{1}{R_1 C_1}\$=1000 -> \$R_1=\frac{1}{\omega_1 C_1}\$ and, if \$C_1=47*10^-9\$ F, \$R_1=2.1*10^4 \Omega\$

So I can choose a resistence between 2.1*10^4 and 2.1*10^5 ohm.

I have choosen it such that \$R_1=5*10^4 \Omega\$

So \$\omega_1=\frac{1}{R_1 C_1}=4.25.5\$ rad/s

And \$\omega=10 \omega_1=4.25*10^3\$ rad/s.

Then, this is the proceeding about the second condition:

\$5\omega<<\omega_2\$ -> \$5\omega=\frac{1}{10}\omega_2\$ -> \$\omega=\frac{1}{50}\omega_2\ = \frac{1}{50R_2C_2}\$

If I choose a capacity of 47 nF, I obtain the second resistence \$R_2=100\Omega\$

Is my proceeding correct? Thank you so much!

(The image of the circuit is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOiml.jpg))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have derived a range of values for R1 based on two different values of w1. Choose one value of w1 that meets the requirements i.e. 500 rad/s and calculate R1 based on C1 being 47nF.

Do the same for R2 based on (say) w2 = 20,000 rad/sec. I'd reduce the value of capacitance on this circuit to something like 10nF or 4.7nF (see small print below)

In all other respects what you have done is perfectly good. I prefer deciding on limiting values for frequency first, then doing one set of calculations.

**Small print** - I am assuming that you are using op-amps to create an integrator and differentiator. If you are, be aware that the integrator will require a high value feedback resistor to maintain DC conditions and stop the op-amp output clipping against either positive or negative supply rail. This high-value resistor (1Mohm minimum) will have a slight detrimental effect on it being a true integrator. For the differentiator i would also put a small resistance in series with the capacitor to prevent noise and other issues. It probably needs to be a few tens of ohms, possible even 10 ohms.

Here's a picture of a Low-pass circuit followed by a high-pass circuit - note that these only approximate to integration and differentiation: -
[image]
The blue trace is called Vint and is the output from the "integrator". The red trace is the output of both circuits together (cascaded). I have purposefully made the impedances R1 and C1 very low so that the diff circuit attached does not "load" the output too much. I've also made C2 and R2 high-ish so that they don't form a big load to the R1,C1 circuit.

I believe that if you go for 500 rad/s and 20,000 rad/s you'll need R1 = 100R, C1 = 20uF, R2 = 51K and C2 = 1nF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have thought that \$omega_1=\frac{1}{10}\omega\$ and so I have found the extreme values that w1 can assume. And then I have calculated R1. Is it wrong?

Comment: @sunrise your calculations appear to be good - BTW i have modified my answer slightly with more information. Using 0.1w (or 100 rad/sec is your choice and I can't argue against it.

Comment: ok! I don't know the op-amps, I'll try to explain the circuit: the circuit is composed by an integrator and a derivator. In the integrator I have a risistor and then a capacitor. In the derivator I have a capacitor and then a resistor. And I have a function generator and an oscilloscope.. I have to "see" \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$

Comment: I'n not sure to have understood: if I want an high impedence \$Z_{in}\$ and a low impedence \$Z_{out}\$, I have to put in the integrator a resistence minimum 1Mohm? thanks again

Comment: If you were using operational amplifiers to create "perfect" integrators and differentiators, you have to take care of real-life circuit problems by making them slightly imperfect with these added resistors. Maybe if you include a circuit diagram of what you are planning to do i can explain easier and show how op-amps make it work better.

Comment: added the diagram!

Comment: @sunrise - this isn't going to work how you expect it to because of loading effects. The output of the integrator does not want to be fed to the input of the differentiator circuit. The input of the differentiator will "load" the integrator and make it behave incorrectly. Another point too... these are not true differentiators or integrators - these are just filter circuits. You'll need to add them around op-amps to get what you need. Maybe explain what you are trying to do and that'll make more sense?

Comment: @sunrise here's a link to a stack of pictures all showing opamps as integrators https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=op+amp+integrator&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=3YZ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=qRBkUYemOoyQ4ASI-oC4Aw&ved=0CEQQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=904

Comment: well, to tell the truth, the assignment is "plan a circuit made as in the picture and such as is valid the aforementioned relation between the omegas." And the current that flows in the second part of the circuit must be little. Could you help me?

Comment: @sunrise I've added a picture with an explanation - hope this helps. I think if you "keep" R1 and C1 impedances low compared to R2 and C2 it will be Ok as you want it. Try and maximize "distance" in frequency between the two points w1 and w2 to get least cross-contamination

Comment: oh thank you! but I have a doubt.. the impedence of a capacitor is given by Z=1/(wC), isn't it?

Comment: @sunrise - correct and good luck

Comment: I'm sorry.. could you have a little of patience again? r1 and c1 are in parallel while c2 and r2 are in serie... aren't they?

Comment: @sunrise - look at the circuit and graphs I attached to my answer for circuit. They have the same circuit references as you circuit.

Comment: I have seen it! :) but I have a (stupid) doubt: r1 and c1 are in parallel, while c2 and r2 are in series.. is it correct? (thank you a lot!)

Comment: @sunrise it's not important but.... R1 and C1 are in series, and R2 and C2 are in series, then both circuits are joined together to make a mess of series ideas or parallel ideas.

Comment: but the way that I follow to calculate the total impedance of each circuit depends on the fact that resistor and capacitor are in series or in parallel!!

Comment: @sunrise I think if you want to extend your question to understanding the impedances this is best done by opening a new question - I keep getting "suggestions" from the site that we should be having these discussions in the chat-room. If you are happy that your original question has been answered please do consider up-voting and/or "accepting" the answer(s) by clicking on the up arrow markers near the top of my answer. I'll be ready to answer other questions and it'll be easier for other folk to provide alternative answers than wading through this question!!!

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer when I read it for the first time, but I haven't the required reps. And, of course, the accepted answer is yours :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8262/discussion-between-sunrise-and-andy-aka)

Answer (score 0):

In more conventional terms, your input frequency is only from 160 Hz to 1.6 kHz.  You didn't say what you want to do with the result of these differentiations and integrations, but surely there is something downstream.

The obvious answer is to run the signal into a microcontroller and do all the math digitally.  That doesn't suffer from part tolerances, and you can keep as many bits as you want to avoid loosing anything.  Small signals don't pick up more relative noise just because they are small, and there is no long term drift.

I'd look a one of the Microchip dsPICs for this.  You could get 12 bit samples at 10x the highest frequency of interest, which is 16 kHz in this case.  A dsPIC 33F at 40 MHz instruction rate can execute 2500 instructions per sample.  That's a lot.  That allows for many many 32 or 48 bit fixed point operations per sample, far more than you need.  You could even do significant floating point operations in that many instructions.